# Working with Mongo result objects - problems with _id field

Tags: php, json, mongodb

Im pretty new to MongoDB and have some minor troubles with it. In Mongo, every object I get from my database has that special `_id` field. This field is of course needed to uniquely identify my object.

Now in PHP, my object is returned as an array with the special _id field.

```
Array (
    [_id] => MongoId Object (
        [$id] => 547dc96b5c5db8a80f000029
    )
    [somekey] => somevalue
)
```

When encoding to JSON, sending through some frontends and decoding it back in PHP again, the _id field has of course been cast/destroyed.

To avoid this, I think I'll have to cast the _id field after getting it from the Mongo database.

```
Array (
    [_id] =>  547dc96b5c5db8a80f000029
    [somekey] => somevalue
)
```

Now it can safely be encoded and decoded however I want.

**But** will this object work when saved in the MongoDB again? Will Mongo use the _id field as it's Mongo ObjectId even in this form or do I need to recast it accordingly?

Is there a better way for this?

---

**Update**
I just tried saving an object several times with it's _id as MongoId and with it's _id as a string. Objects with MongoId are **not** replacing those with same _id as string, type matters here.

This would meand that every object I get from the db needs it's _id to be manually cast and after it's received from some JSON using client again, I would have to recast evrry _id to MongoId again.
This might have a severe performance impact when loading larger lists of objects.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Change string represented `_id` back to an object? `$array['_id'] = new MongoId('547dc96b5c5db8a80f000029');`

Comment: @Glavić So you think I will have to recast every _id back to MongoId objects before sending them to the database again?

Comment: Easiest way would be to test this, but I think that if `_id` is presented as string, it will replace object in mongodb. Please try it...

Comment: @Glavić Tried it. see update. Strange...

Comment: `So _id is treated as unique field, no matter what type it has.` is how mongodb works. Field `_id` is **always** unique field, no matter what type it is; and this is the how it should work.

Comment: @Glavić Yes, but the real problem still persists. How best to send such objects over JSON to clients and back to PHP again without loosing the _id and it's special type.

Comment: `This might have a severe performance impact when loading larger lists of objects. Is there a better way?` I don't think this will be severe performance impact, test it. On other hand, you can still create your own type for _id field, integer or string, it doesn't have to be an object...

Comment: @Glavić Since no better alternative was found and I'm now using conversion for all objects entering/leaving the database, if you post that as an answer, i could accept that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change string represented field `_id` back to an [`MongoId`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php) object:

```php
$array['_id'] = new MongoId($array['_id']);
```

I don't think this will be severe performance impact, best to test it. On other hand, you can still create your own type for _id field, integer or string, it doesn't have to be an object.